# Multiple programs with same names for kernels

Tags: opencl, nvidia

I have the following situation:

Two threads handling two OpenCL devices which share the same context. Each thread loads a different version of the OpenCL device code, creates a `cl::Programm` instance and compiles the code for his specific `cl::Device`. However, the `createKernels` function after successfully building the program fails with error code -47 =

> CL_INVALID_KERNEL_DEFINITION if the function definition for __kernel function given by kernel_name such as the number of arguments, the argument types are not the same for all devices for which the program executable has been built.

With multiple `cl::Context` instances (one for each device) this worked well. If I look at the OpenCL class diagram (http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/classDiagram.html) I don't see why is should not be able to use multiple programs with multiple kernels within one context as they are clearly distinguishable via the associated programs.

I'm using the OpenCL implementaton of Nvidia within CUDA SDK 5.5. The questions that arises for me are:

Is this a general misunderstanding of the OpenCL structure and there is a rule that says that every kernel within a context must have a unique name, or is this one of Nvidia's non OpenCL standard confirm ways of handling this particular use case?

I really want multiple devices within one context to be able to use copy from one `cl::Buffer` to another even if their memory resides on different devices.

Comment: Could you please post the definition of your kernel function? It looks like there is smt wrong there. Maybe you are declaring some "double" type witch is only available is 1 device out of 2.

Comment: To make it a little bit clearer: The code differs only in some __constant values at global scope. The code is compiling on two Nvidia Tesla M2090.